# Adding a wildcard IP range to htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I thought my syntax below would work great to allow IP Ranges using an asterix as the wildcard, but no joy...

Any idea what would work here?

My IP changes the last two batches of numbers....

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^112\.*\.*\.*$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/denied.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you confirm if you want to look for only IPs which are starting from `112` to send to denied.html OR there could be ranges? By looking of your statement `My IP changes the last two batches of numbers....` Kindly confirm it once.

Comment: _Aside:_ I would also consider changing your `RewriteRule` to trigger an error document (internally) as in your commented out directive. Your current rule will result in a 302 external redirect which is generally undesirable for something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following. Considering that you don't want to allow any IP starting from `112` then we can keep it simple regex. We need NOT to mention any other digits here since you are not concerned about it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^112\.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/denied.html
```

Comment: Nice answer @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 4):

The IP matching regex was incomplete. It was looking for an IP of 112 followed by zero to three dots. That would obviously never happen.

This would work

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^112\.
```

By stripping the last part you would now match any address starting with 112 followed by a dot. This is pretty broad in what it could match. But should be enough for your purpose.

A more complete version would be this, where you specify the complete address.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^112\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

This code snippet should work for you

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^112\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/denied.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hey no worries. Yeah +1 for yours too :)